# Room DB select List of all items + total sum of these items

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 queryes from ROOM DB:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM basket_items")
Flowable<List<BasketItem>> getAll();

@Query("SELECT SUM(count*amount) FROM basket_items")
Flowable<Long> totalSum();
```

How can I merge this queryes to one query? And what type of model it will be return?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ user8035311 in general, I just ask this. How can I rewrite 2 queries to one

Answer (score 2):

Room Queries can return POJO (not an `@Entity`), and therefore you can make temporary model for your DAO.

As I already asked in comments, I don't know what you're trying to achieve (as in what value you want to get from those queries).

But hopefully this example might help:

**YourDao.java**

```
@Query("SELECT name AS nameItem, (count * amount) AS countItem FROM basket_items")
Flowable<List<CountedBasketItem>> getAllCounted();

static class CountedBasketItem {
    String nameItem;
    Long countItem;
}
```

**Additional Answer**

What you want to return List and total sum is not possible by the query. SUM is aggregation method, you aggregate the list.

So there're 2 options that you might want to do:

1. Use `GROUP BY` in your query
2. Or execute those 2 Flowable and get the result.

Comment: In this implementation(i try it) each item has total. I need somthing like this class BasketItemWithToatal{private List<BusketIItem> items; private long total;}

Comment: I added some answer you might want to check

Answer (score 0):

you can create field totalSum in your pojo and use this query

```
@Query("SELECT *,SUM(count*amount) AS totalSum FROM basket_items")
Flowable<List<BasketItem>> getAll();
```

you will get all table and the field totalSum is SUM(count*amount)